# Can we use "later" instead of "from now"?

Tags: american-english, time, dates

It is Jan and you will fly to Japan in March. In American English, you say: "I will fly to Japan 2 months from now". Can you instead say "I will fly to Japan 2 months later"?

Is there any other alternative for "from now" in this case?

Comment: No, "later" doesn't work, unless you're relating it to some other event. ("I will fly to Korea in March, and then to Japan two months later.")  You can say, "I will fly to Japan **in** two months."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"2 months later" implies that you have mentioned a date already and are referring to a point two months after that date, e.g. **I'll be checking out some hotels next week, and I will fly to Japan 2 months later.**

As for an alternative, you may replace "from now" in the sentence by prepending the word "in" to the time measurement: **I will fly to japan in two months.**

Comment: Thank you. But, when you say "two months from now I will do this" it means exactly two months from now. But, "in two months" means any time from now until two months from now. Right?

Comment: @Sus20200 No problem! And nope, "in two months" also means "exactly two months from now" :) You might be thinking of "*within* two months", which does mean "any time from now until two months from now".